# How to use GroupBy and Select in list using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, list

I have a script that reads XML page store some of the content into a list.

After I have a list I would like to group the results by a name.

Here is what I have done

```
DashboardViewModel vm = new DashboardViewModel();

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string result = client.DownloadString(url);

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(result);

    foreach (XElement row in doc.Descendants("row"))
    {
        var ticket = new Ticket();

        ticket.company_name = row.Element("company_name").Value;
        ticket.team_name = row.Element("team_name").Value;
        ticket.Age = Parser.decimalVal(row.Element("Age").Value);
        ticket.resource_list = row.Element("resource_list").Value;

        ticket.Closed_Flag = Parser.boolVal(row.Element("Closed_Flag").Value);
        ticket.Date_Entered_UTC = Parser.dateTimeVal(row.Element("Date_Entered_UTC").Value);
        ticket.Date_Closed_UTC = Parser.dateTimeVal(row.Element("Date_Closed_UTC").Value);


        tickets.Add(ticket);

    }

}

vm.summaryByTeam = tickets.GroupBy(x => x.team_name)
                  .Select(x =>
                      new DashboardTicketTotal()
                  {
                      category = x.Key,
                      totalTickets = x.Count(),
                      totalOpenTickets = x.Where(c => c.Closed_Flag == false).Count(),
                      averageOpenDaysFormatted = String.Format("{0:0.##}", x.Average(c => c.Age)),
                      averageDaysToCloseFormatted = String.Format("{0:0.##}", x.Where(c => c.Closed_Flag == true).Average(c => c.Age)),
                      totalClosedInPast30Days = x.Where(c => c.Closed_Flag == true && c.Date_Closed_UTC > now.AddDays(-30)).Count()
                  }).ToList();
```

Here is my DashboardViewModel class

```
public class DashboardViewModel
{

    public int totalOpen { get; set; }
    public int totalClosed { get; set; }
    public int over30DaysAge { get; set; }
    public decimal? totalAge { get; set; }

    public int totalTickets { get; set; }

    public decimal? averageAge { get; set; }
    public string averageAgeFormatted { get; set; }
    public decimal? averageOpenAge { get; set; }
    public decimal? totalOpenAge { get; set; }
    public int totalClosedIn30Days { get; set; }

    public int totalOpenTicketsOver30Day { get; set; }
    public int totalCloseTicketsOver30Day { get; set; }


    public int totalTicketOver30DaysOld { get; set; }
    public int createdInPast30Days { get; set; }
    public int age0To15 { get; set; }
    public int age16To30 { get; set; }
    public int age31To60 { get; set; }
    public int age61To90 { get; set; }
    public int age91Plus { get; set; }

    public List<DashboardTicketTotal> summaryByTeam { get; set; }

    public List<DashboardTicketTotal> summaryByCenter { get; set; }

    public DashboardViewModel()
    {
        over30DaysAge = 0;
        totalAge = 0;
        totalTickets = 0;
        createdInPast30Days = 0;
        averageOpenAge = 0;
        summaryByTeam = new List<DashboardTicketTotal>();
        summaryByCenter = new List<DashboardTicketTotal>();
    }
}
```

However the line

```
 .Select(x =>
                          new DashboardTicketTotal()
```

is giving me an error

```
 Sequence contains no elements
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements




[InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements]
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Average(IEnumerable`1 source) +2578534
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Average(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 selector) +58
   ConnectWiseReports.Controllers.<>c__DisplayClass30.<DashBoard>b__13(IGrouping`2 x) in c:....ReportsController.cs:102
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +157
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +381
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   ConnectWiseReports.Controllers.ConnectWiseReportsController.DashBoard() in c:...ReportsController.cs:100
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +156
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9651516
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: it fails on `averageDaysToCloseFormatted = String.Format("{0:0.##}", x.Where(c => c.Closed_Flag == true).Average(c => c.Age)),` when there are no objects with `Closed_Flag==true`.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov I get the same error even if I comment out the 2 lines with the format

Comment: What do you expect as average formatted value when there are no objects?

Comment: I would expect 0. But even when I comment the 2 lines I get the same error

Comment: So when you comment `averageDaysToCloseFormatted =` line do you still get the error?

Comment: Correct. The same error

Comment: Debug and place a breakpoint on the vm.SummaryByTeam line. Check the "tickets" object and see if it contains any rows. If developing in VS, you can use the Immediate window to view the object properties pretty easily.

Comment: You shouldn't get the error. Try to rebuild the project, check that you compile the correct project, etc.

Comment: @BoydP tickets contains 204 rows

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov you are right. but how would I replace the average with 0 if the Closed_flag never == true?

Comment: Use `averageDaysToCloseFormatted = String.Format("{0:0.##}", x.Where(c => c.Closed_Flag == true).Average(c => (decimal?)c.Age) ?? 0)`

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov When I comment the line everything works. Then I uncommented it and added the casting like you have will still give me an error

Comment: Did you copy my code as it is? Note that `?? 0` should be outside of `Average` method.

Comment: That worked!! thank you very much! Please    post an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code fails on the following line:

```
averageDaysToCloseFormatted = String.Format("{0:0.##}",
    x.Where(c => c.Closed_Flag == true)
     .Average(c => c.Age))
```

When there are no objects with set `Closed_Flag`, then the sequence is empty and the `Average` cannot be calculated. One way to solve the problem is to cast `Age` to `decimal?` (make it nullable), then the average of empty sequence of nullable values will be `null`. Then we use null-coalescing operator (??) to replace resulting null average value with 0.

```
averageDaysToCloseFormatted = String.Format("{0:0.##}",
    x.Where(c => c.Closed_Flag == true)
     .Average(c => (decimal?)c.Age) ?? 0)
```